# Searching multiple tables' fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have many temporary tables in this naming convention: `temp_table_20153112`. From those tables, there's a field called `Manager`. We want to identify those tables where the `Manager IS NULL`. 
Here is what I have at the moment which lists all the tables that start with `temp_table_` but I do not know how to requery the result-set. Any ideas?

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
       c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE t.name LIKE '%temp_table_%'
    AND c.name = 'Manager'
```

Comment: `Manager IS NULL` - column or values in this column?

Comment: @Devart values in this column.

Comment: so your expected output is just the name of the tables where at least one of the values in column Manager IS NULL?

Comment: @ughai The output should be the name of the tables only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
    SELECT '
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP(1) ''' + name + ''' AS tbl FROM ' + name + ' WHERE Manager IS NULL'
    FROM (
        SELECT name = QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id])) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name)
        FROM sys.objects o
        JOIN sys.columns c ON o.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
        WHERE o.name LIKE 'temp_table_%'
            AND c.name = 'Manager'
            AND c.is_nullable = 1
    ) t
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 13, '')

--PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Output -

```
SELECT TOP(1) '[dbo].[temp_table_2342]' AS tbl FROM [dbo].[temp_table_2342] WHERE Manager IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP(1) '[dbo].[temp_table_234]' AS tbl FROM [dbo].[temp_table_234] WHERE Manager IS NULL
UNION ALL
...
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but executes as a stored procedure. Is it possible to be as not an sp or function?

Comment: If shortly - no. Please provide a bit more info about what's you need to do and where...

Comment: Basically I want it to feed a grid on a page, so I am getting the results from a datareader. I have accepted your answer. If it's too much trouble don't worry about it. Great answer

Comment: @alwaysVBNET ok... Anyway you are welcome ;) and have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE
    @table_name SYSNAME,
    @sql VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE tables CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT DISTINCT t.name AS table_name
    FROM sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID 
    WHERE t.name LIKE '%temp_table_%' 
        AND c.name = 'Manager'
OPEN tables 
FETCH NEXT FROM tables INTO @table_name
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ' + @table_name + ' WHERE [Manager] IS NULL) RAISERROR(''' + @table_name + ''',0,1) WITH NOWAIT'
    EXECUTE(@sql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM tables INTO @table_name
END
CLOSE tables
DEALLOCATE tables
```